# Post base64 encoded video to server, OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, encoding, base64, androidhttpclient

I need to send larger video files (and other files) to server with base64 encode.

I get out of memory exception, because I want to store the file in the memory (in `byte[]`) then encode it to `string` with `Base64.encodeToString`. But how can I encode the file and send it out on-the-air and/or using less memory? Or how can I do this better?

To the request I using now `MultipartEntityBuilder` after I build it, I send it out to the server with post method and with the file I need to send other data too. So I need to send both in one request and the server only accepts files with base64 encoded.

OR

Because I using Drupal's REST module to create content from posts, it's another solution for me, if I can send normal post with a normal form. (like the browser does) The problem is, I can't find, just only one solution. When you call the `<endpoint>/file` url and you pass four things, these are:

```
array("filesize" => 1029, // file size
      "filename" => "something.mp4", //file name
      "uid" => 1, // user id, who upload the file
      "file" => "base64 encoded file string")
```

After this request I get an fid, which is the uploaded file's id. I need to send this with the real content, when I create node. If I can send the file with normal post mode (without encode) like the browser does at form send, it would be better.

Comment: if you need to send images(4-5MB) to server i will give you solution.But i am not familiar to video to base64 encoding.

Comment: nop, I need to send bigger things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to send larger video files (and other files) to server with base64 encode.

You should consider getting a better server, one that supports binary uploads.

> I get out of memory exception, because I want to store the file in the memory (in byte[]) then encode it to string with Base64.encodeToString.

That will not work for any significant video. You do not have heap space for this.

> But how can I encode the file and send it out on-the-air and/or using less memory? Or how can I do this better?

You can implement a streaming converter to base64 (read the bytes in from a file and write the bytes out to a base64-encoded file, where you are only processing a small number of bytes at a time in RAM). Then, upload the file along with the rest of your form data.

Comment: I've edited my q. And how can I implement that? I thing I need to write a new encoder for that...

Comment: What you write is true, but I found a better solution, in the rest module it possible to send in binary these files with this url: <endpoint>/file/create_raw